# Glyph not printed

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols

I want to make a neat-looking PDF document from TeX source. The TeX file is mainly ASCII text with few non-ASCII symbols (arrows in schemes, custom bullets marking list items, hieroglyphs in contributor's name in credits section, etc.).

The TeX source is, in turn, built by Sphinx from rst sources.

The non-ASCII symbols are not printed in the output PDF because there are no glyphs for them in the font used throughout the document by default.

So, I made a shell script that scans TeX Live installation directory for .pfb, .otf and .ttf files and for each found font it creates TeX document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multido}

\font\testedfont="[/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/wadalab/dgj/dgjkj.pfb]"

\font\basictextfont="cmr10"

\title{Find glyph for Unicode 80A5 in dgjkj.pfb}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{glyphslotnum}
\newcommand\findglyphslotnum{}

\newcounter{totalglyphnum}
\newcommand\findtotalglyphnum{}

Test glyphs

{\basictextfont{Font filename: dgjkj.pfb}}

\testedfont
\renewcommand\findglyphslotnum{\the\XeTeXcharglyph"80A5}
\setcounter{glyphslotnum}{\findglyphslotnum}
\renewcommand\findtotalglyphnum{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\testedfont}
\setcounter{totalglyphnum}{\findtotalglyphnum}

%\multido{\i=0+1}{\value{totalglyphnum}\relax}{
%{\basictextfont\i:\,}{\testedfont\XeTeXglyph\i}
%}

\basictextfont
dgjkj.pfb: total \number\value{totalglyphnum} glyphs

\ifnum\value{glyphslotnum}>0{\message{Glyph for 80A5 exists in dgjkj.pfb (slot \number\value{glyphslotnum})}Glyph for Unicode 80A5 exists in dgjkj.pfb at slot \number\value{glyphslotnum}.

It looks like [{\testedfont\XeTeXglyph\value{glyphslotnum}}] (by $\backslash$XeTeXglyph) 
or [{\testedfont{\char"80A5}}] (by $\backslash$char) 
or [{\testedfont{\symbol{"80A5}}}] (by $\backslash$symbol)
}\fi

\end{document}
```

It gives output like this (copy here: [dgjkj.pfb_U80A5.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y0d4RLAgeSRq13LX48lin_tL-NaxpXcN/view?usp=drive_link)):
[image]

Uncommenting multido loop will provide the list of all glyphs in the font.

I found fonts with glyphs for all Unicode symbols I need, but I have problem with symbol U279C ("Heavy Round-Tipped Rightwards Arrow"). It was found in the font file fonts/type1/urw/zapfding/uzdr.pfb (message "Glyph for 279C exists in uzdr.pfb (slot 168)" is printed while compiling), but building PDF fails with error, the full output is as follows:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./find_glyph_pfb_uzdr.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multido/multido.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>))
No file find_glyph_pfb_uzdr.aux.
Glyph for 279C exists in uzdr.pfb (slot 168) [1] (./find_glyph_pfb_uzdr.aux)
xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.

Output file removed.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file find_glyph_pfb_uzdr.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on find_glyph_pfb_uzdr.log.
```

The full log can be found here: [find_glyph_pfb_uzdr.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UELgjDrzrLP4Qv1mAMKWjmobVIeibRwC/view?usp=sharing).

So, the question is - what should I do to print that glyph?

Upd: the failing TeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multido}

\font\testedfont="[/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/zapfding/uzdr.pfb]"

\font\basictextfont="cmr10"

\title{Find glyph for Unicode 279C in uzdr.pfb}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{glyphslotnum}
\newcommand\findglyphslotnum{}

\newcounter{totalglyphnum}
\newcommand\findtotalglyphnum{}

Test glyphs

{\basictextfont{Font filename: uzdr.pfb}}

\testedfont
\renewcommand\findglyphslotnum{\the\XeTeXcharglyph"279C}
\setcounter{glyphslotnum}{\findglyphslotnum}
\renewcommand\findtotalglyphnum{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\testedfont}
\setcounter{totalglyphnum}{\findtotalglyphnum}

%\multido{\i=0+1}{\value{totalglyphnum}\relax}{
%{\basictextfont\i:\,}{\testedfont\XeTeXglyph\i}
%}

\basictextfont
uzdr.pfb: total \number\value{totalglyphnum} glyphs

\ifnum\value{glyphslotnum}>0{\message{Glyph for 279C exists in uzdr.pfb (slot \number\value{glyphslotnum})}Glyph for Unicode 279C exists in uzdr.pfb at slot \number\value{glyphslotnum}.

It looks like [{\testedfont\XeTeXglyph\value{glyphslotnum}}] (by $\backslash$XeTeXglyph) 
or [{\testedfont{\char"279C}}] (by $\backslash$char) 
or [{\testedfont{\symbol{"279C}}}] (by $\backslash$symbol)
}\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, it is surely accessible via `\ding{220}` after having loaded the `pifont` package. But maybe this is not what you intend to do. Maybe the mapping is wrong.

Comment: it would be easier to test your issue if you provided the failing example and not only the one that works. But beside this: why are you trying to find your glyphs in type1 fonts instead of using some open type font which xelatex can handle much better?

Comment: Thanbk you, Jasper! Adding \ding{220} works. Still, I want to treat all those Unicode in a unified way (suitable for scripting). May be digging sources of pifont will give me a clue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Sorry, Ulrike. Added it.

Comment: Thank you, Mensch! :)